# Why docker sync files with map folder extremely slow? (Ubuntu)

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

On my local machine (Ubuntu 18.04, 8GB RAM, i5, HDD) I have two docker-compose files with my laravel project

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  backend-network:
    driver: bridge
  frontend-network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  &app-service app: &app-service-template
    container_name: k4fntr_app
    build:
      context: ./docker/php-fpm
      args:
        UID: ${UID?Use your user ID}
        GID: ${GID?Use your group ID}
        USER: ${USER?Use your user name}
    user: "${UID}:${GID}"
    hostname: *app-service
    volumes:
      - /etc/passwd/:/etc/passwd:ro
      - /etc/group/:/etc/group:ro
      - ./:/var/www/k4fntr
    environment:
      APP_ENV: "${APP_ENV}"
      CONTAINER_ROLE: app
      FPM_PORT: &php-fpm-port 9000
      FPM_USER: "${UID:-1000}"
      FPM_GROUP: "${GID:-1000}"
    networks:
      - backend-network

  &queue-service queue:
    <<: *app-service-template
    container_name: k4fntr_queue
    restart: always
    hostname: *queue-service
    depends_on:
      - app
    environment:
      CONTAINER_ROLE: queue

  &schedule-service schedule:
    <<: *app-service-template
    container_name: k4fntr_schedule
    restart: always
    hostname: *schedule-service
    depends_on:
      - app
    environment:
      CONTAINER_ROLE: scheduler

  &sportlevel-listener sportlevel_listener:
    <<: *app-service-template
    container_name: k4fntr_sl_listener
    restart: always
    hostname: *sportlevel-listener
    ports:
      - "${SPORTLEVEL_LISTEN_PORT}:${SPORTLEVEL_LISTEN_PORT}"
    depends_on:
      - app
    environment:
      CONTAINER_ROLE: sl_listener

  &php-fpm-service php-fpm:
    <<: *app-service-template
    container_name: k4fntr_php-fpm
    user: 'root:root'
    restart: always
    hostname: *php-fpm-service
    ports: [*php-fpm-port]
    entrypoint: /fpm-entrypoint.sh
    command: php-fpm --nodaemonize
    networks:
      - backend-network
      - frontend-network

  echo-server:
    container_name: k4fntr_echo
    image: oanhnn/laravel-echo-server
    volumes:
     - ./:/app
    environment:
      GENERATE_CONFIG: "false"
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - "6001:6001"
    networks:
      - backend-network
      - frontend-network

  redis:
    container_name: k4fntr_redis
    image: redis
    restart: always
    command: redis-server
    volumes:
      - ./docker/redis/config/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
      - ./docker/redis/redis-data:/data:rw
    ports:
      - "16379:6379"
    networks:
      - backend-network
```

and docker-compose-dev.yml

```
version: '3.7'

volumes:
  redis-data:
  pg-data:
  k4fntr_sync:
    external: true

services:
  &app-service app: &app-service-template
    container_name: k4fntr_app
    build:
      context: ./docker/php-fpm
      args:
        UID: ${UID?Use your user ID}
        GID: ${GID?Use your group ID}
        USER: ${USER?Use your user name}
    user: "${UID}:${GID}"
    hostname: *app-service
    volumes:
      - /etc/passwd/:/etc/passwd:ro
      - /etc/group/:/etc/group:ro
      - k4fntr_sync:/var/www/k4fntr:nocopy
    environment:
      APP_ENV: "${APP_ENV}"
      CONTAINER_ROLE: app
      FPM_PORT: &php-fpm-port 9000
      FPM_USER: "${UID:-1000}"
      FPM_GROUP: "${GID:-1000}"
    networks:
      - backend-network

  &php-fpm-service php-fpm:
    <<: *app-service-template
    container_name: k4fntr_php-fpm
    user: 'root:root'
    restart: always
    hostname: *php-fpm-service
    ports: [*php-fpm-port]
    entrypoint: /fpm-entrypoint.sh
    command: php-fpm --nodaemonize -d "opcache.enable=0" -d "display_startup_errors=On" -d "display_errors=On" -d "error_reporting=E_ALL"
    networks:
      - backend-network
      - frontend-network

  mail:
    container_name: k4fntr_mail
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    ports:
      - "1025:1025"
      - "8025:8025"
    networks:
      - backend-network

  nginx:
    container_name: k4fntr_nginx
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/config/default:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - k4fntr_sync:/var/www/k4fntr:nocopy
    depends_on:
      - *php-fpm-service
    ports:
      - "${NGINX_LISTEN_PORT}:80"
    networks:
      - frontend-network

  database:
    container_name: k4fntr_database
    build: ./docker/postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      ENV: ${APP_ENV}
      TESTING_DB: ${DB_DATABASE_TESTING}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_DATABASE}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/postgres/prod/:/prod
      - ./docker/postgres/pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
    networks:
      - backend-network
```

The problem is the fact that when I change some files in my project I have to wait a lot of time. From 15 to 40 seconds. It is impossible for local development. How can I solve this problem?

I learned some information with similar problems with other OS such as Mac or Windows, but I can't found the same problems with Linux.

Comment: Bind mounts on native Linux should be pretty fast (in theory, imperceptibly faster than accessing image content).  Do you have more profiling information on where the time is going?  Also note that the `docker-compose.yml` file can be made _much_ simpler (delete the `networks:`, `hostname:`, `container_name:`, and the `entrypoint:` and `command:` specifications that duplicate what's in the Dockerfile) and this will help readers understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I thought that second file (docker-compose-dev.yml) overrided first file. I mean php-fpm section. If you look at docker-compose-dev you can see that there is the command

```
command: php-fpm --nodaemonize -d "opcache.enable=0" -d "display_startup_errors=On" -d "display_errors=On" -d "error_reporting=E_ALL"
```

Actually I used first file (what is very strongely, because I used the command

> docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml -f docker-compose.yml up

) and my opcache was cached. This was the main reason why I had to wait so long